# Can I Remove xmlrpc.php completely?

Tags: security, xml-rpc

My site is getting a lot of malicious traffic to domain.com/xmlrpc.php, to the point that the server is not being able to handle it.

I tried to disable it via the wp-config.php, by adding this line:

```
add_filter('xmlrpc_enabled', '__return_false');
```

And I also tried [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-xml-rpc/), but neither method seemed to have worked.

Now I am considering to completely remove the php file, but I would like to be sure I won't destroy other things.

Does anyone know if it's safe to remove that file?

Comment: Please show _how_ you tried to disable it via your config file.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: `add_filter()` isn't available inside the `wp-config.php`. Move that to a plugin.

Comment: Gotcha, but ain't the plugin I mentioned doing that? Also, I am still curious to know whether or not I can remove the file altogether.

Comment: Dunno, take a look at its source.